# Salesforce check box does not pass value to controller

Tags: community

I have a check box in my VF page and I am trying to pass the value to controller, but when i use debug log, it is showing 'false'always. Please help.

### My VF: (chunk only)

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Account" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="Account" extensions="MyController">
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label">
                    <Label style="padding-bottom:2px;color:#333; float: right;"> Darksite: </Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-8 control-label required">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sysDarkSite}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### My controller:(Chunk only)

```
global class MyController
{
  public Boolean sysDarkSite {get; set;}

 public MyController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController)
    {
    }

 public PageReference Update()
    {
    Boolean boolDarkSite = sysDarkSite;
    system.debug('boolDarkSite :' +boolDarkSite );
    List<Custom_Obj__C> oCusObj = [Select Id, NEX_Dark_Site__c from 
    Custom_Obj__C];
    oCusObj[0].NEX_Dark_Site__c = sysDarkSite;
    system.debug('oCusObj [0].NEX_Dark_Site__c:'+oCusObj [0].NEX_Dark_Site__c);
    update oCusObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you call the `Update` method?

Comment: Hi Tushar, forget about the call. Functionality wise I want to get the checkbox value in the form and update it to a checkbox field (NEX_Dark_Site__c ) in my custom SFDC object.

Answer (score 0):

your are not calling update method in vfpage and you have to use actionfunction or actionsupport or create a wrapper class and bind in main class so you can get the value

add this variable in apex controller

```
public boolean myCheckbox {get; set;}
```

add this in vfpage

```
 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}>
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!Update}" />
  </apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Comment: Hi, I am calling my controller function in the command button and in my controller I already have the getter setter. Still value comes as false always.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are having a form tag in your visual force page and you are updating the record using command button.
Your code should work fine after you make couple of changes to your code.

1. Add `<apex:form>` tag to visualforce page
2. Add `<apex:commandButton>` to visalforce page and call your action method.

This is the working code

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Account" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="Account" extensions="MyController">
    <apex:form>
        <html>
            <body>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label">
                            <Label style="padding-bottom:2px;color:#333; float: right;"> Darksite: </Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-8 control-label required">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sysDarkSite}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updateRecord}"/>
        </html>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
global class MyController
{
    public Boolean sysDarkSite {get; set;}

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController)
    {
    }

    public PageReference updateRecord()
    {
        Boolean boolDarkSite = sysDarkSite;
        system.debug('boolDarkSite :' +boolDarkSite );
        List<Custom_Obj__C> oCusObj = [Select Id, NEX_Dark_Site__c from 
                                       Custom_Obj__C];
        oCusObj[0].NEX_Dark_Site__c = sysDarkSite;
        system.debug('oCusObj [0].NEX_Dark_Site__c:'+oCusObj [0].NEX_Dark_Site__c);
        update oCusObj;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, I have everything in place. I am not in a position to paste my 3k lines of code here. I am passing other fields (text box, dropdown) from the same form and everything comes out fine. If you see my system.debug lines, I am getting false in all the places. Anything special need to be done to pass boolean value from vfp to apex class and store it in a custom SFDC object ?

Comment: Hi @sfdcrat, you don't need to do anything special to pass boolean's value to controller. It works same as it works for any other types of variables. I guess your boolean variable might be getting initialised once again somewhere in your update method. And one question, as you are using standard set controller,  how many checkboxes do you see in your page ?

Comment: Hi @Vijay, I observed a strange thing. I have added this check box to another place in my code and passed the boolean via another function and it works fine. But the place I used earlier is still not working although I used same procedure to pass values. :(

Comment: Hi @sfdcrat, I feel that your boolean variable must be getting set to false somewhere in your update method. Try renaming that boolean variable to something else and see if it works.